# Append dictionary to pandas dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a requirement to create a dictionary within a loop and append them to a pandas data frame with matching key name of dict and column name of data frame. The key value pairs of dictionary in each iteration could be different. An empty pandas data frame `df_podcast` have been defined at the beginning with all possible keys in the dictionary.

Below is the sample of a code which is not completed yet

```
df_podcast=pd.DataFrame(columns=podcast_cols)

podcast_dict={}
for j in range(len(podcast[0])):
    if podcast[0][j].tag=="key":
        podcast_dict[podcast[0][j].text]=podcast[0][j+1].text
### Have to append dict to pandas df ############
```

I have append podcast_dict to df_podcast. Podcast is actually a list of lists, here I'm just considering only 1st row of the list

Comment: Last after loop is possible use `df = pd.DataFrame(podcast_dict)` ?

Comment: The answer here is very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973687/create-new-dataframe-in-pandas-with-dynamic-names-also-add-new-column

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame([podcast_dict], columns=podcast_dict.keys())
df_podcast = pd.concat([df_podcast, df], axis =0).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to simply append new data from a created dictionary within a loop to an existening Dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(n):
    dict_new = dict(i)
    df = df.append(dict_new, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

**NOTE:** As long as the keys in your created dictionary are the same, appending it to an existing dataframe shouldn't be cumbersome.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774826/append-dictionary-to-data-frame)

Answer (score 5):

IIUC:

What you need to do is to build your dictionary with your loop, then at then end of your loop, you can use your dictionary to create a dataframe with:

```
df1  = pd.DataFrame(podcast_dict)
```

And append using `pd.concat`:

```
df_podcast = pd.concat([df_podcast, df1])
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for the answer. But the key names , no of key value pairs etc in my dictionary will be different in each iteration. I want to insert the value to the data frame where key of the dictionary matches with column name of the data frame. 
for example :- if the first iteration dictionary has only two item { "Track id":100 , "Play count":10 }. I should insert values only in Track id and play count columns of first row of the data frame.

Comment: Did you try it? Pandas does automatic index alignment, and column are an index. I did try witb some dummy data to verify and order doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0):

It is very late but I am always struggling and my preferred way is not documented here. Maybe it helps somebody else:

```
item_default = { "id":None,"name":"Untitled" }
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=item_default.keys())
#some loop
for podcast in podcasts:
    item=item_default
    item["name"]=podcast.text
    df_podcast = pd.concat([df_podcast, pd.Dataframe.from_records([item])],ignore_index=True)
```

The advantages are that you do not need a proper order in the item and you are free to add multiple items per iteration if needed.