# append dictionary to data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a function, which returns a dictionary like this:

```
{'truth': 185.179993, 'day1': 197.22307753038834, 'day2': 197.26118010160317, 'day3': 197.19846975345905, 'day4': 197.1490578795196, 'day5': 197.37179265011116}
```

I am trying to append this dictionary to a dataframe like so:

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
output.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
print(output.head())
```

Unfortunately, the printing of the dataframe results in an empty dataframe. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you creating and empty dataframe to append to?

Is there a reason you can't just use pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary) ?

Comment: @GeorgeLPerkins I know but I have to ultimately append several dictionaries.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The previous answer (user alex, answered Aug 9 2018 at 20:09) now triggers a warning saying that appending to a dataframe will be deprecated in a future version.

A way to do it is to transform the dictionary to a dataframe and the concatenate the dataframes:

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
df_dictionary = pd.DataFrame([dictionary])
output = pd.concat([output, df_dictionary], ignore_index=True)
print(output.head())
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Since the other one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51775051/7924573) is deprecated.

Comment: It's a pity this is now the accepted way of doing things. Adding a dict to a DF is super common for me and I always have to look up the correct way of doing it now

Answer (score 218):

**Doesn't work starting pandas==2.0.0**, **deprecated since 1.4**

You don't assign the value to the result.

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
output = output.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
print(output.head())
```

Comment: output = output.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True) makes all the difference ...

Comment: oh. I expected dictionary append to work in place like list append, but it doesn't.

Comment: As of v 1.4, `append` is deprecated in favor of `concat`.  See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append).

Answer (score 9):

I always do it this way because this syntax is less confusing for me.
I believe concat method is recommended though.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
>>>df 
col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4

d={'col1': 5, 'col2': 6} 
df.loc[len(df)]=d

>>>df 
col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     5     6
```

Note that iloc method won't work this way.