# I added a row to Dataframe of pandas 3 times. However, only the last line is added

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, python-3.6

I wrote a function.
Dataframe was added 3 times using append.
But the result is only added one last time.

======
・It was an error to declare the dataframe type outside of the function first.
So I declared it in a function.

・Later, I wrote Dataframe outside of def AddDataframe (ymd, sb, vol) :. Then I got an error. The error is below.

## NameError: name 'Hisframe10' is not defined

```
import pandas as pd
def AddDataframe(ymd,sb,vol):
  data={'yyyymmdd':[],
      'Sell':[],
      'Buy':[],
      'Volume':[],        
      'JPX':[],
      'FutPrice':[]}
  Hisframe8=pd.DataFrame(data)
  Hisframe8
  print('')
  print('Hisframe8= ',Hisframe8)
  adddata={'yyyymmdd':[ymd],
    'Sell':[sb],
    'Buy':['Nan'],
    'Volume':[vol],           
    'JPX':[-1],
    'FutPrice':[0.]}
  Hisframe10=pd.DataFrame(adddata)
  Hisframe10
  return(Hisframe8.append(Hisframe10))
AddDataframe('2019-05-03','sell',123)
AddDataframe('2019-05-04','sell',345)
AddDataframe('2019-05-05','sell',456)
#Hisframe10  #err
```

======
I want to add 3 lines of data frame.
How should I do it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIWqN.jpg

Comment: you need to pass in a dataframe to append _to_

Comment: Hisframe8=pd.DataFrame(data) should be outside the function; you overwrite the Dataframe each time you call the function (by creating a new Dataframe).

Comment: @wpercy
Thank you for writing.

Comment: @GeorgPoe
Thank you for explaining the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make `Hisframe8` as global

```
import pandas as pd

Hisframe8=pd.DataFrame(columns=['yyyymmdd','Sell','Buy','Volume','JPX','FutPrice'])

def AddDataframe(ymd,sb,vol):
    global Hisframe8
    adddata={'yyyymmdd':[ymd],'Sell':[sb],'Buy':['Nan'],'Volume':[vol],'JPX':[-1],'FutPrice':[0.]}
    Hisframe10=pd.DataFrame(adddata)
    Hisframe8 = Hisframe8.append(Hisframe10)


AddDataframe('2019-05-03','sell',123)
AddDataframe('2019-05-04','sell',345)
AddDataframe('2019-05-05','sell',456)
print(Hisframe8)
```

Comment: I see. You use [global] in the function. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that you create an additional dataframe and append that to the first.
You can instead just append the dictionary to the existing df as shown here: [append dictionary to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774826/append-dictionary-to-data-frame)

Also a better style maybe would be to define the dataframe you are inserting into first, since that is not the primary use of your function.

My suggestion:

```
structure = {'date':[], 'Sell':[], 'Buy':[], 'Volume':[], 'JPX':[], 'FutPrice':[]}
df = pd.DataFrame(structure)

def add_data(df, date, sb, vol):
   insert_dict = {'date':[date], 'Sell':[sb], 'Buy':[np.nan],
                  'Volume':[vol], 'JPX':[-1], 'FutPrice':[0.]}

   return df.append(insert_dict , ignore_index = True)

df_appended = add_data(df, '2019-01-01', 'sell', 456)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much. However, if you add three lines as shown below, only the last line is included. Please let me know if you notice any points.

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
structure = {'date':[], 'Sell':[], 'Buy':[], 'Volume':[], 'JPX':[], 'FutPrice':[]}
df = pd.DataFrame(structure)

def add_data(df, date, sb, vol):
   insert_dict = {'date':[date], 'Sell':[sb], 'Buy':[np.nan],'Volume':[vol], 'JPX':[-1], 'FutPrice':[0.]}
   return(df.append(insert_dict , ignore_index = True))

df_appended = add_data(df, '2019-01-01', 'sell', 123)
df_appended = add_data(df, '2019-01-02', 'sell', 345)
df_appended = add_data(df, '2019-01-03', 'sell', 456)
df_appended

Comment: @saru999 you need to reference the newly created df in the function. if you want to add more lines to "df_appended" you need to call the function like this:

> add_data(df_appended, '2019-01-01', 'sell', 123).

Otherwise you only append to "df" which is actually not changed, since we create the new dataframe "df_appended".