# panda dataframe append issue

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Any idea why pandas dataframe append is inserting NaN values for only 3 columns out of 50 columns where as dictionary has the real value

checking whether dict has proper values or not before appending, its shows real values:

```
 for x,y in dict.items():
     print(x, '-', y)
```

but after appending to dataframe its showing as NaN, no clue why its happening.

`df = df.append(dict,ignore_index=True,sort=False)`

Any idea where its going wrong ?

Comment: can you show us df, and dict?

Comment: `df = pd.concat(dict.values(),keys=dict.keys())`

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: @ignoring gravity you can think of df as a empty dataframe and dict is a python dictionary where it has 50 key value pairs

Comment: to mention those 3 columns are last 3 columns in a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The dict must be a dataframe or series

```
DataFrame.append(df, dict, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=None)
```

Comment: dict is a dictionary in my case. i am able to append the data successfully with dictionary... only 3 columns are reflecting as NaN out of 50 columns

Comment: Well, you need to either use dictionaries and then transform them to dataframe, or dataframes and append dataframes. Do not append dictionary to dataframe....

Comment: hope we can append dictionary to dataframe without any issues and its valid right ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774826/append-dictionary-to-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i wasted a lot of time. i am seeing df.head() and assuming i didnt get the proper data but after seeing df values got inserted properly :)