# When Appending Dict to DataFrame, I get "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, append

I'd like to append a Dictionary as a new row to an existing DataFrame. The keys in the Dict are the same as the columns in the DataFrame. Code example:

```
in: df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(3))], columns=['Col {}'.format(x) for x in range(3)])
out: 
       Col 0  Col 1  Col 2
    0      0      1      2
```

Now I set up my dict: `new_row = {'Col 0':1, 'Col 1':1, 'Col 2':1}`

Appending, as shown in the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774826/append-dictionary-to-data-frame) and example 2 [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-one-row-in-an-existing-pandas-dataframe/), however, throws an error:

```
in: df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
out: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: it works fine in my environemt, have you changed variables like `df` before appending?

Comment: You probably wrote something like `df.append = new_row` previously; erasing and restarting the kernel might work

Comment: Thanks @mustafa and Jiang, restarting the kernel got it done. And df.append = new_row is exactly what I'd done somewhere previously. Thank you!