# How to create variables and read several excel files in a loop with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```py
L=[('X1',"A"),('X2',"B"),('X3',"C")]
for i in range (len(L)):
    path=os.path.join(L[i][1] + '.xlsx')
    book = load_workbook(path)
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
    ''.join(L[i][0])=pd.read_excel(xls,'Sheet1')

File "<ipython-input-1-6220ffd8958b>", line 6
    ''.join(L[i][0])=pd.read_excel(xls,'Sheet1')
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I have a problem with pandas, I can not create several dataframes for several excel files but i don't know how to create variables

I'll need a result that looks like this :

X1 will have dataframe of A.xlsx
X2 will have dataframe of B.xlsx
.
.
.

**Solved :**

```py
d = {}

for i,value in L:
    path=os.path.join(value + '.xlsx')
    book = load_workbook(path)
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
    df = pd.read_excel(xls,'Sheet1')
    key = 'df-'+str(i)
    d[key] = df
```

Comment: Does any of that work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: i get :  File "<ipython-input-1-6220ffd8958b>", line 6
    ''.join(L[i][0])=pd.read_excel(xls,'Sheet1')
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: I'm not sure actually on what you're trying to do - are you trying to loop over a bunch of excel files, and put them all into separate dataframes, named as you wish?

Comment: Yes !  i need to create diffirents dataframe from diffirents excel files

Answer (score 1):

## Main pull:

I would approach this by reading everything into 1 dataframe (loop over files, and concat):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = [] #generate list for files to go into

path_of_directory = "path/to/folder/"

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_of_directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

output_data = [] #blank list for building up dfs

for name in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(name)
    df['name'] = os.path.basename(name)
    output_data.append(df)

total = pd.concat(output_data, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
```

### Then:

From then you can interrogate the df by using `df.loc[df['name'] == 'choice']`

### Or (in keeping with your question):

You could then split into a dictionary of dataframes, based on this column. This is the best approach...

```
dictionary = {}
df[column] = df[column].astype(str)

col_values = df[column].unique()

for value in col_values:
    key_name = 'df'+str(value)
    dictionary[key_name] = copy.deepcopy(df)
    dictionary[key_name] = dictionary[key_name][df[column] == value]
    dictionary[key_name].reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

return dictionary
```

The reason for this approach is discussed here:
[Create new dataframe in pandas with dynamic names also add new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973687/create-new-dataframe-in-pandas-with-dynamic-names-also-add-new-column) which basically says that dynamic naming of dataframes is bad, and this `dict` approach is best

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
files_xls = ['all your excel filename goes here']
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls:
  data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
  df = df.append(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: That's not working , because i need different df ( like df per excel file ) so i need to get df1 , df2 , df3.... without append , Thank's

Comment: Maybe you can append one column with one static excel filename and then filter the data for the particular need.