# Changing variable names and creating new ones dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a list of numbers

```
ex_list = [0, 3, 5] The amount of numbers is dynamic(usually).
```

I have a data frame variable:

```
ex_df = pd.read_csv(*some df*)
```

Is it possible to create a copy of this ex_df for each of the variables in ex_list and name it:

ex_df_0

ex_df_3

ex_df_5

Each of those will be a copy of ex_df

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: You can also look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40974699/6590393. Loop over `ex_list` and store data frames in a dictionary, as suggested in the answer shared by @paul too. Dynamic variable names is not a good practice.

Comment: I'd recommend you use a directory structure instead of creating variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this would be to use `locals()` function -

**Code**

```py
ex_list = [0, 3, 5]
ex_df = pd.read_csv(*some df*)

for i in ex_list:
    locals()['ex_df_'+str(i)] = ex_df.copy()
```

This will create 3 dataframes, `ex_df_0, ex_df_3, ex_df_5` which will all be copies of dataframe `ex_df`.

Comment: looks like a solution. Thanks. I will try to think of a different approach to my problem as per @RachayitaGiri 's suggestion that it is bad practice for dynamic variable creation.

Comment: It's worth noting that the documentation for [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) does come with a note that says: *The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.*

Comment: @JonClements I do not understand that statement, contents of `locals()` will get modified each time we define a new df anyway. Could you please elaborate a bit more ?