# How to automate naming of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-import

Suppose I have something stored in variable x and now i want to import some datasets and assign name- A_x to the first data, B_x to the second dataset and so on..
Say  x = customer
So I want datasets to be saved as A_customer, B_customer and so on.
How can I do this in python 3.0

Comment: Maybe use a dictionary so you can save the objects by unique names

Comment: As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973687/create-new-dataframe-in-pandas-with-dynamic-names-also-add-new-column) mentions "Creating variables with dynamic names is typically a bad practice. I think the best solution for your problem is to store your dataframes into a dictionary and dynamically generate the name of the key to access each dataframe."