# Dataframe is not defined when trying to concatenate in loop (Python - Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following list (named columns_list):

```
['total_cases',
 'new_cases',
 'total_deaths',
 'new_deaths',
 'total_cases_per_million',
 'new_cases_per_million',
 'total_deaths_per_million',
 'new_deaths_per_million',
 'total_tests',
 'new_tests',
 'total_tests_per_thousand',
 'new_tests_per_thousand',
 'new_tests_smoothed',
 'new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand',
 'tests_units',
 'stringency_index',
 'population',
 'population_density',
 'median_age',
 'aged_65_older',
 'aged_70_older',
 'gdp_per_capita',
 'extreme_poverty',
 'cvd_death_rate',
 'diabetes_prevalence',
 'female_smokers',
 'male_smokers',
 'handwashing_facilities',
 'hospital_beds_per_thousand',
 'life_expectancy']
```

Those are columns in two dataframes: US (df_us) and Canada (df_canada). I would like to create one dataframe for each item in the list, by concatenating its corresponding column from both df_us and df_canada.

```
for i in columns_list:
    
    df_i = pd.concat([df_canada[i],df_us[i]],axis=1)
```

Yet, when I type

```
df_new_deaths
```

I get the following output: name 'df_new_deaths' is not defined

Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973687/create-new-dataframe-in-pandas-with-dynamic-names-also-add-new-column

Comment: use the list entries as an id column and store one big df, or create a dictionary of dataframes

Comment: `df_i = ...` will not create `df_new_deaths` but only `df_i` - you should use dictionary `dfs = dict()` and then `dfs[i] = ...` and you will have `dfs["new_deaths"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're not actually saving the dataframes
- `df_new_deaths` is never defined
- Add the dataframe of each column to a list and access it by index
- Also, since only one column is being concated, you will end up with a pandas Series, not a DataFrame, unless you use `pd.DataFrame`

```py
df_list = list()
for i in columns_list:
    
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df_canada[i],df_us[i]],axis=1)))
```

- add the dataframes to a dict, where the column name is also the key

```py
df_dict = dict()
for i in columns_list:
    
    df_dict[i] = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df_canada[i],df_us[i]],axis=1))
```